# Ignoring EOF on std::cin in C++

Tags: c++, console, stdin

I have an application that implements an interactive shell, similar to how the Python console / irb works.  The problem now is that if the user accidentally hits `^D` EOF is issued and my `getline()` call returns an empty string which i treat as "no input" and display the prompt again.

This then results in an endless loop that prints the prompt.

Now in Python I would solve that problem by catching `EOFError`, but in C++ no exception is raised I could catch and there doesn't seem to be a setting on `cin` to ignore EOF.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct solution thanks to litb:

```
if (!getline(std::cin, str)) {
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Can't do that yet.  For reasons unknown to my I just got a new account although I logged in with my existing one :-/

Comment: @mitsuhiko Probably you logged in using a different openid account.

Comment: Got back my account.  Seems like stackoverflows OpenID delegate support is a bit buggy

Answer (score 7):

If it could not read anything, it sets the `failbit`. Just test the stream in an if condition, and clear the bit:

```
if(!getline(std::cin, myline)) {
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cout << "you should enter something" << std::endl;
}
```

Internally, the sequence is this way in your case:

- Wait on the terminal for a string. Terminal will block until the user emits a newline. Two probable error cases possible

  1. User presses immediately EOF. This will make `getline` read nothing at all, and it will set the `failbit` and the `eofbit`.
  2. User inputs something and then presses EOF. This will make `getline` consume something and then it hits EOF while trying to get the next character. This cause `eofbit` to be set.
- You will try to read something again. The extraction function will create an object of type `istream::sentry` which checks in what state the stream is. If any of the errorbits are set, it will cause the extraction function to immediately return. That caused the endless loop before.

A call to `clear()` clears all error bits, and you can go on reading your stuff again.

Answer (score 1):

The [`getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline.html) function signals errors by using the following bits:

- eofbit
- failbit
- badbit

Try checking these before you proceed.

Comment: I can check them, but I can't ignore EOF that way.  So I can't continue to use the input stream. I could only quit the application which is not what I want.

Comment: darnit, you beat me by 1min :) +1

Comment: dirkgently, the link links to istream::getline though. chances are high he uses std::getline ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline.html ).

Comment: mitsuhiko, just do  if(!getline(std::cin, myline)) { std::cin.clear(); std::cout << "behave, please!" << std::endl; }

Comment: @litb: Possible. I get the benefit of the doubt ;-)

Comment: restored answer below containing an example.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.horstmann.com/cpp/pitfalls.html

You can use code like:

```
while (cin)
{  int x;
   cin >> x;
   if (cin) a.push_back(x);
}
```

Comment: @ypnos the code was meant to be an example, not a solution. Anyway, we now have a solution, thanks to Litb

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in other answers using cin.clear() was described as a possible solution.

Another trick is that you use other means to process the input from the console than the typical standard in by setting the terminal to another mode so you can process Ctrl+D directly. In RAW mode or others, you gain more direct access to the input and control sequences from the user side (like Ctrl+D or Ctrl+C) are not handled elswhere anymore.

Some libraries you may try to gather more information (or even save coding time):

- [GNU Readline](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html)
- [Useful Terminal I/O Library](http://utio.sourceforge.net/) ½
- [NCurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) (which is very powerful)

½ You can find some information about your problem in the docs [here](http://utio.sourceforge.net/#CKeyboard).