# C++ Ignoring CTRL D from user

Tags: c++

In my program, I am trying to check the user's input. I want him to press a given character. But my code doesn't ignore pressing <kbd>CTRL+D</kbd>, it becomes an infinite loop.

```
char ch;
cin >> ch;
while(ch != 'c' && ch != 'C'){
    if (cin.eof()){
        cin.clear();
    }
    cin >> ch;
}
```

Is there a way to fix this?

When I do this:

```
 char ch;
        cin >> ch;
        while(ch != 'c' && ch != 'C'){
            if (cin.eof()){
                std::clearerr(stdin);
            }
            if (cin.eof()){
                std::clearerr(stdin);
            }
            cin >> ch;
        }
```

The second if is still true.

I am trying to do something like Press any key. I can"t seem to figure it out.

Comment: But I don't want it to break, I want the user to input the character.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674413/ignoring-eof-on-stdcin-in-c

Comment: And is there a way to end the whole programm then?

Comment: Maybe `Ctrl+C`?  Bit brutal though.

Comment: Tried the clearerr. But still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);` at the start.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. At the start of what?

Comment: Of the mushroom... er. of the program.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Doesn't seem it did anything.

Comment: Works for me somehow.

Comment: ctrl-D key (on some systems) injects the end of stream marker onto `std::cin` to simulate the end of stream. It does not close std::cin and if you reset the state you can keep reading (from std::cin). Not sure what you are asking! It looks like expected behaviour to me (if after seeing the end of stream you reset the state, then you will keep reading). Note: this is extremely dangerous as it will cause an infinite loop if you redirect a file to standard input of your application).

Comment: Normally you would loop until you see `C` or `c` or there is no more input. If there is no more input then you should stop (there is no more input). No more input is indicated by the end of stream marker (i.e. user pressing Ctrl-D).

Comment: @MartinYork Maybe I should have said that I am trying to do something like Press any key. I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: @KaPe The `std::cin` is buffered. So you probally cant just read a key. The stream has to be flushed before your code gets any characters (on std::cin this is usally done after the `enter key` is pressed. If you want to poll the keyboard for key events you need to use a library that does that.